# SwiftUI - Two Finger Tap gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Well, I have been looking around google and couldn't manage to find a good way to create an OnTwoFingerTap detection, if anyone could help me out please :) I would be greatful

So in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132827) there was a solution, which had errors: `Error build: Reference to generic type 'UIViewRepresentableContext' requires`

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext) -> UIView
{
    let view = UIView()
    let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap(sender:)))
   
    /// Set number of touches.
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
   
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext)
{
}
```

Comment: May be [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132827) will help you.

Comment: I'm actually looking at this as you were writing it, but I have an error and I'm not sure how to fix it: `Error build: Reference to generic type 'UIViewRepresentableContext' requires arguments in <...>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you thought I meant by "answers don't belong in questions," but I have separated the question from the answer for you this time as an example. Don't expect other users to do the same.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by switchhing UIViewRepresentContext to Context

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView
{
    let view = UIView()
    let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap(sender:)))
   
    /// Set number of touches.
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
   
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context)
{
}
```